# How to use yuicompressor in node application to minify javascript

Tags: yui-compressor

Can anyone spot an example where yuicompressor is used in node application to minify javascript or css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "node-minify" node-module, once can minify javascript or css. In this module we can specify whether to mimize using yui-compressor or using uglifyjs, google composure etc